# mousedown event not firing on tablet / mobile, HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, touch-event

I am having an issue with canvas not registering mousedown events on tablet, I have been trying for a while but nothing is working, even changing the mousedown to touchstart in the code, implementing hammer.js, jquery mobile, any help would be appreciated, everything works on desktop, just not an anything that requires touch gestures

```
var gestures = function(config){

var conf = {
    debug: true,
    draw: true,
    drawColor: "##f8f07e",
    drawWidth: 5,
    autoTrack: true,
    allowRotation: true,
    inverseShape: true,
    points: 33
};

var d;
var ctx;
var tracking = false;
var ob = this;

this.gestures = [];
this.points = [];

this.construct = function(){
    d = doc_size();
    //copying configuration
    for(var opt in config){
        conf[opt] = config[opt];
    }

    if(document.getElementById("gestures_canvas"))
    {
        ctx = document.getElementById("gestures_canvas").getContext("2d");
    }
    else if(conf.draw)
    {
        //create canvas for drawing

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.setAttribute("width", d.width + "px");
        canvas.setAttribute("height", d.height + "px");
        canvas.style.position = "fixed";
        canvas.style.top = "0px";
        canvas.style.left = "0px";
        canvas.id = "gestures_canvas";
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }
    if(conf.autoTrack || conf.draw)
    {
        add_event(document.body, "mousedown", this.Down);
        add_event(document.body, "mouseup", this.Up);




        tracking = true;
    }

    this.reset();
};




this.pauseTracking = function(){
    tracking = false;
};

this.resumeTracking = function(){
    tracking = true;
};

this.addGesture = function(name, points, callback){
    if(conf.inverseShape){
        var inverse = [];
        for(var i = points.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            inverse.push(points[i]);
        }
        var gesture = {};
        gesture.name = name;
        gesture.callback = callback;
        var map = resample(inverse, inverse.length, conf);

        gesture.map = vectorize(map, conf.allowRotation);
        this.gestures.push(gesture);

    }

    var gesture = {};
    gesture.name = name;
    gesture.callback = callback;
    var map = resample(points, points.length, conf);
    gesture.map = vectorize(map, conf.allowRotation);
    this.gestures.push(gesture);
};

this.resolve = function(points){

    if(points.length > 1)
    {
        this.reset();
        var map = resample(points, points.length, conf);

        var ivect = vectorize(map, conf.allowRotation);

        var maxScore = 0;
        var match = "none";
        for(var i = 0; i < this.gestures.length; i++)
        {
            var dist = optCosDist(this.gestures[i].map, ivect);
            var score = 1/dist;

            if(score > maxScore)
            {
                maxScore = score;
                match = this.gestures[i];
            }
        }
        if(match.callback)
        {
            match.callback(match.name);
        }
    }
};

this.reset = function(){
    this.points = [];
};

this.clear = function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
};

//gesture auto tracking
//mouse down
this.Down = function(event){
    ob.reset();
    if(conf.draw)
    {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
        ctx.lineWidth = conf.drawWidth;
        ctx.strokeStyle = conf.drawColor;
        ctx.lastX = event.clientX;
        ctx.lastY = event.clientY;
    }
    if(conf.autoTrack && tracking)
    {
        var point = {};
        point.x = event.clientX;
        point.y = event.clientY;
        ob.points.push(point);
    }
    add_event(document.body, "mousedown", ob.Move);
};

//mouse move
this.Move = function(event){
    if(conf.draw)
    {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(ctx.lastX, ctx.lastY);
        ctx.lineTo(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.lastX = event.clientX;
        ctx.lastY = event.clientY;
    }
    if(conf.autoTrack && tracking)
    {
        var point = {};
        point.x = event.clientX;
        point.y = event.clientY;
        ob.points.push(point);
    }
};
//mouse up
this.Up = function(event){
    if(conf.autoTrack && tracking)
    {
        ob.resolve(ob.points);
    }
    remove_event(document.body, "mousemove", ob.Move);
};


//some helping internal functions

var optCosDist = function(gestureV, inputV){
    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < gestureV.length; i += 2)
    {
        a = a + gestureV[i]*inputV[i] + gestureV[i+1]*inputV[i+1];
        b = b + gestureV[i]*inputV[i+1] - gestureV[i+1]*inputV[i];
    }
    var angle = Math.atan2(b,a);

    return Math.acos(a*Math.cos(angle) + b*Math.sin(angle));
};

//distance [PROTRACTOR]
var Distance = function(u, v){
    var x = (u.x - v.x);
    var y = (u.y - v.y);
    return Math.sqrt((x*x)+(y*y));
};

var pathLength = function(points, n){
    var distance = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        distance = distance + Distance(points[i-1], points[i]);
    }
    return distance;
};

var resample = function(points, n){
    var subLength = pathLength(points, n)/(conf.points-1);
    var distance = 0;
    var newpoints = [];
    var elem ={};
    elem.x = points[0].x;
    elem.y = points[0].y;
    newpoints.push(elem);

    var i = 1;
    while (i < points.length && newpoints.length < (conf.points-1))
    {
        var subdist = Distance(points[i-1], points[i]);
        if((distance + subdist) >= subLength)
        {
            var elem2 = {};
            elem2.x = points[i-1].x + ((subLength - distance)/subdist)*(points[i].x - points[i-1].x);
            elem2.y = points[i-1].y + ((subLength - distance)/subdist)*(points[i].y - points[i-1].y);
            //add point
            newpoints.push(elem2);
            points.splice(i,0,elem2);
            distance = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            distance = distance + subdist;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    var elem3 = {};
    //adding last point
    elem3.x = points[points.length-1].x;
    elem3.y = points[points.length-1].y;
    newpoints.push(elem3);

    return newpoints;
};

var centroid = function(points){
    var center = {};
    center.x = 0;
    center.y = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
    {
        center.x = center.x + points[i].x;
        center.y = center.y + points[i].y;
    }
    center.x = center.x/(points.length-1);
    center.y = center.y/(points.length-1);
    return center;
};

var translate = function(points,center){
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
    {
        points[i].x = points[i].x - center.x;
        points[i].y = points[i].y - center.y;
    }
    return points;
};

var vectorize = function(points, sensit){
    var vector = [];

    var center = centroid(points);
    var points = translate(points, center);

    var lenkis = Math.atan2(points[1].x, points[1].y);
    var delta = lenkis;
    if(sensit)
    {
        var base = (Math.PI/4)*Math.floor((lenkis+(Math.PI/8))*(4/Math.PI));
        delta = base-lenkis;
    }
    var summa = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
    {
        var newx = points[i].x*Math.cos(delta) - points[i].y*Math.sin(delta);
        var newy = points[i].x*Math.sin(delta) + points[i].y*Math.cos(delta);
        vector.push(newx);
        vector.push(newy);
        summa = summa + newx*newx + newy*newy;
    }

    var magnitude = Math.sqrt(summa);
    for(var i = 0; i < vector.length; i++)
    {
        vector[i] = vector[i]/magnitude;
    }
    return vector;
};

//get document dimensions
var doc_size = function(){
    var docsize = new Object();
    docsize.width = 0;
    docsize.height = 0;
    docsize.width = Math.max(
        Math.max(document.body.scrollWidth, document.documentElement.scrollWidth),
        Math.max(document.body.offsetWidth, document.documentElement.offsetWidth),
        Math.max(document.body.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
    docsize.height = Math.max(
        Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
    return docsize;
};

//add event
var add_event = function(element, type, listener){
    if(element.addEventListener)
    {
        element.addEventListener(type, listener, false);
    }
    else
    {
        element.attachEvent('on' +  type, listener);
    }
};

//remove event
var remove_event = function(element, type, listener){
    if(element.removeEventListener)
        element.removeEventListener(type, listener, false);
    else
        element.detachEvent('on' +  type, listener);
};

this.construct();
```

}

Answer (score 7):

I've had to do this recently, so you can follow in my footsteps here.

To get your game working on mobile devices, you'll have to follow **2 steps:**

- **A)** Change all `mousedown`, `mousemove`, and `mouseup` events to `touchstart`, `touchmove`, and `touchend` (straight-up replace them in Notepad via Find & Replace).
- **B)** Replace every instance of `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` with the following:

clientX ↓

```
(event.targetTouches[0] ? event.targetTouches[0].pageX : event.changedTouches[event.changedTouches.length-1].pageX)
```

And clientY ↓

```
(event.targetTouches[0] ? event.targetTouches[0].pageY : event.changedTouches[event.changedTouches.length-1].pageY)
```

And again, just use Find & Replace.

**The above commands are long/complicated, because** `ontouchend` doesn't contain a `targetTouches` object, and the above examples can be dropped in for **all** contexts (touchstart, touchmove, *and* touchend) via Find & Replace and will work on **all** Android versions.

One last thing, you may also have to put in `event.preventDefault()` at the very end of each touchstart/touchmove event handler to prevent the mobile browser from thinking the page is scrolling.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Followed all of you steps to a T, still couldn't get it to work, not too sure where I'm going wrong, it's working still with all the changes on desktop, just still not working on tablet/mobile

Comment: Add a `window.onerror = function(a,b,c) { alert(a+b+c); }` to see if any errors occur on the mobile devices

Comment: safari doesn't support touch event api though? what should we do for Safari browser?

Comment: Super, thanks! I utilized event.pageX, instead of event.clientX, but step B works all the same.   Note: safari support for iOS does exist https://caniuse.com/?search=touchstart

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this to work, stuck some code in the head to detect mobile and use the gesture script, and then the desktop uses the mouse script, a bit of a jerry rig of code but it works, if anyone can help make it nice please get in contact

```
if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
|| /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))){ isMobile = true;}

----------end of head code---------------

 if(isMobile==true){
var gestures = function(config){
var conf = {
    debug: true,
    draw: true,
    drawColor: "#000000",
    drawWidth: 5,
    autoTrack: true,
    allowRotation: true,
    inverseShape: true,
    points: 33
};

var d;
var ctx;
var tracking = false;
var ob = this;

this.gestures = [];
this.points = [];

this.construct = function(){
    d = doc_size();
    //copying configuration
    for(var opt in config){
        conf[opt] = config[opt];
    }

    if(document.getElementById("gestures_canvas"))
    {
        ctx = document.getElementById("gestures_canvas").getContext("2d");
    }
    else if(conf.draw)
    {
        //create canvas for drawing
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.setAttribute("width", d.width + "px");
        canvas.setAttribute("height", d.height + "px");
        canvas.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas.style.top = "0px";
        canvas.style.left = "0px";
        canvas.id = "gestures_canvas";
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }
    if(conf.autoTrack || conf.draw)
    {
        add_event(document.body, "touchstart", this.Down);
        add_event(document.body, "touchend", this.Up);
        tracking = true;
    }

    this.reset();
};

this.pauseTracking = function(){
    tracking = false;
};

this.resumeTracking = function(){
    tracking = true;
};

this.addGesture = function(name, points, callback){
    if(conf.inverseShape){
        var inverse = [];
        for(var i = points.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            inverse.push(points[i]);
        }
        var gesture = {};
        gesture.name = name;
        gesture.callback = callback;
        var map = resample(inverse, inverse.length, conf);

        gesture.map = vectorize(map, conf.allowRotation);
        this.gestures.push(gesture);

    }

    var gesture = {};
    gesture.name = name;
    gesture.callback = callback;
    var map = resample(points, points.length, conf);
    gesture.map = vectorize(map, conf.allowRotation);
    this.gestures.push(gesture);
};

this.resolve = function(points){

    if(points.length > 1)
    {
        this.reset();
        var map = resample(points, points.length, conf);

        var ivect = vectorize(map, conf.allowRotation);

        var maxScore = 0;
        var match = "none";
        for(var i = 0; i < this.gestures.length; i++)
        {
            var dist = optCosDist(this.gestures[i].map, ivect);
            var score = 1/dist;

            if(score > maxScore)
            {
                maxScore = score;
                match = this.gestures[i];
            }
        }
        if(match.callback)
        {
            match.callback(match.name);
        }
    }
};

this.reset = function(){
    this.points = [];
};

this.clear = function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
};

//gesture auto tracking
//mouse down
this.Down = function(event){
    ob.reset();
    if(conf.draw)
    {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
        ctx.lineWidth = conf.drawWidth;
        ctx.strokeStyle = conf.drawColor;
        ctx.lastX = (event.targetTouches[0] ? event.targetTouches[0].pageX :        event.changedTouches[event.changedTouches.length-1].pageX)
;ctx.lastY = (event.targetTouches[0] ? event.targetTouches[0].pageY :     event.changedTouches[event.changedTouches.length-1].pageY)
;
    }
    if(conf.autoTrack && tracking)
    {
        var point = {};
        point.x = (event.targetTouches[0] ? event.targetTouches[0].pageX : event.changedTouches[event.changedTouches.length-1].pageX)
;
        point.y = (event.targetTouches[0] ? event.targetTouches[0].pageY : event.changedTouches[event.changedTouches.length-1].pageY)
;
        ob.points.push(point);
    }
    add_event(document.body, "touchmove", ob.Move);
};

//mouse move
this.Move = function(event){
    if(conf.draw)
    {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(ctx.lastX, ctx.lastY);
        ctx.lineTo((event.targetTouches[0] ? event.targetTouches[0].pageX :     event.changedTouches[event.changedTouches.length-1].pageX)
, (event.targetTouches[0] ? event.targetTouches[0].pageY : event.changedTouches[event.changedTouches.length-1].pageY)
);
            ctx.stroke();
        ctx.lastX = (event.targetTouches[0] ? event.targetTouches[0].pageX : event.changedTouches[event.changedTouches.length-1].pageX)
;
        ctx.lastY = (event.targetTouches[0] ? event.targetTouches[0].pageY : event.changedTouches[event.changedTouches.length-1].pageY)
;
    }
    if(conf.autoTrack && tracking)
    {
        var point = {};
        point.x = (event.targetTouches[0] ? event.targetTouches[0].pageX : event.changedTouches[event.changedTouches.length-1].pageX)
;
        point.y = (event.targetTouches[0] ? event.targetTouches[0].pageY : event.changedTouches[event.changedTouches.length-1].pageY)
  ;
        ob.points.push(point);
    }
};
//mouse up
this.Up = function(event){
    if(conf.autoTrack && tracking)
    {
        ob.resolve(ob.points);
    }
    remove_event(document.body, "touchmove", ob.Move);
};


//some helping internal functions

var optCosDist = function(gestureV, inputV){
    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < gestureV.length; i += 2)
    {
        a = a + gestureV[i]*inputV[i] + gestureV[i+1]*inputV[i+1];
        b = b + gestureV[i]*inputV[i+1] - gestureV[i+1]*inputV[i];
    }
    var angle = Math.atan2(b,a);

    return Math.acos(a*Math.cos(angle) + b*Math.sin(angle));
};

//distance [PROTRACTOR]
var Distance = function(u, v){
    var x = (u.x - v.x);
    var y = (u.y - v.y);
    return Math.sqrt((x*x)+(y*y));
};

var pathLength = function(points, n){
    var distance = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        distance = distance + Distance(points[i-1], points[i]);
    }
    return distance;
};

var resample = function(points, n){
    var subLength = pathLength(points, n)/(conf.points-1);
    var distance = 0;
    var newpoints = [];
    var elem ={};
    elem.x = points[0].x;
    elem.y = points[0].y;
    newpoints.push(elem);

    var i = 1;
    while (i < points.length && newpoints.length < (conf.points-1))
    {
        var subdist = Distance(points[i-1], points[i]);
        if((distance + subdist) >= subLength)
        {
            var elem2 = {};
            elem2.x = points[i-1].x + ((subLength - distance)/subdist)*(points[i].x - points[i-1].x);
            elem2.y = points[i-1].y + ((subLength - distance)/subdist)*(points[i].y - points[i-1].y);
            //add point
            newpoints.push(elem2);
            points.splice(i,0,elem2);
            distance = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            distance = distance + subdist;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    var elem3 = {};
    //adding last point
    elem3.x = points[points.length-1].x;
    elem3.y = points[points.length-1].y;
    newpoints.push(elem3);

    return newpoints;
};

var centroid = function(points){
    var center = {};
    center.x = 0;
    center.y = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
    {
        center.x = center.x + points[i].x;
        center.y = center.y + points[i].y;
    }
    center.x = center.x/(points.length-1);
    center.y = center.y/(points.length-1);
    return center;
};

var translate = function(points,center){
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
    {
        points[i].x = points[i].x - center.x;
        points[i].y = points[i].y - center.y;
    }
    return points;
};

var vectorize = function(points, sensit){
    var vector = [];

    var center = centroid(points);
    var points = translate(points, center);

    var lenkis = Math.atan2(points[1].x, points[1].y);
    var delta = lenkis;
    if(sensit)
    {
        var base = (Math.PI/4)*Math.floor((lenkis+(Math.PI/8))*(4/Math.PI));
        delta = base-lenkis;
    }
    var summa = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
    {
        var newx = points[i].x*Math.cos(delta) - points[i].y*Math.sin(delta);
        var newy = points[i].x*Math.sin(delta) + points[i].y*Math.cos(delta);
        vector.push(newx);
        vector.push(newy);
        summa = summa + newx*newx + newy*newy;
    }

    var magnitude = Math.sqrt(summa);
    for(var i = 0; i < vector.length; i++)
    {
        vector[i] = vector[i]/magnitude;
    }
    return vector;
};

//get document dimensions
var doc_size = function(){
    var docsize = new Object();
    docsize.width = 0;
    docsize.height = 0;
    docsize.width = Math.max(
        Math.max(document.body.scrollWidth, document.documentElement.scrollWidth),
        Math.max(document.body.offsetWidth, document.documentElement.offsetWidth),
        Math.max(document.body.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
    docsize.height = Math.max(
        Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
    return docsize;
};

//add event
var add_event = function(element, type, listener){
    if(element.addEventListener)
    {
        element.addEventListener(type, listener, false);
    }
    else
    {
        element.attachEvent('on' +  type, listener);
    }
};

//remove event
var remove_event = function(element, type, listener){
    if(element.removeEventListener)
        element.removeEventListener(type, listener, false);
    else
        element.detachEvent('on' +  type, listener);
};

this.construct();
}
} else { 
var gestures = function(config){

var conf = {
    debug: true,
    draw: true,
    drawColor: "#000000",
    drawWidth: 5,
    autoTrack: true,
    allowRotation: true,
    inverseShape: true,
    points: 33
};

var d;
var ctx;
var tracking = false;
var ob = this;

this.gestures = [];
this.points = [];

this.construct = function(){
    d = doc_size();
    //copying configuration
    for(var opt in config){
        conf[opt] = config[opt];
    }

    if(document.getElementById("gestures_canvas"))
    {
        ctx = document.getElementById("gestures_canvas").getContext("2d");
    }
    else if(conf.draw)
    {
        //create canvas for drawing
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.setAttribute("width", d.width + "px");
        canvas.setAttribute("height", d.height + "px");
        canvas.style.position = "absolute";
        canvas.style.top = "0px";
        canvas.style.left = "0px";
        canvas.id = "gestures_canvas";
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }
    if(conf.autoTrack || conf.draw)
    {
        add_event(document.body, "mousedown", this.Down);
        add_event(document.body, "mouseup", this.Up);
        tracking = true;
    }

    this.reset();
};

this.pauseTracking = function(){
    tracking = false;
};

this.resumeTracking = function(){
    tracking = true;
};

this.addGesture = function(name, points, callback){
    if(conf.inverseShape){
        var inverse = [];
        for(var i = points.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            inverse.push(points[i]);
        }
        var gesture = {};
        gesture.name = name;
        gesture.callback = callback;
        var map = resample(inverse, inverse.length, conf);

        gesture.map = vectorize(map, conf.allowRotation);
        this.gestures.push(gesture);

    }

    var gesture = {};
    gesture.name = name;
    gesture.callback = callback;
    var map = resample(points, points.length, conf);
    gesture.map = vectorize(map, conf.allowRotation);
    this.gestures.push(gesture);
};

this.resolve = function(points){

    if(points.length > 1)
    {
        this.reset();
        var map = resample(points, points.length, conf);

        var ivect = vectorize(map, conf.allowRotation);

        var maxScore = 0;
        var match = "none";
        for(var i = 0; i < this.gestures.length; i++)
        {
            var dist = optCosDist(this.gestures[i].map, ivect);
            var score = 1/dist;

            if(score > maxScore)
            {
                maxScore = score;
                match = this.gestures[i];
            }
        }
        if(match.callback)
        {
            match.callback(match.name);
        }
    }
};

this.reset = function(){
    this.points = [];
};

this.clear = function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
};

//gesture auto tracking
//mouse down
this.Down = function(event){
    ob.reset();
    if(conf.draw)
    {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
        ctx.lineWidth = conf.drawWidth;
        ctx.strokeStyle = conf.drawColor;
        ctx.lastX = event.clientX;
        ctx.lastY = event.clientY;
    }
    if(conf.autoTrack && tracking)
    {
        var point = {};
        point.x = event.clientX;
        point.y = event.clientY;
        ob.points.push(point);
    }
    add_event(document.body, "mousemove", ob.Move);
};

//mouse move
this.Move = function(event){
    if(conf.draw)
    {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(ctx.lastX, ctx.lastY);
        ctx.lineTo(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.lastX = event.clientX;
        ctx.lastY = event.clientY;
    }
    if(conf.autoTrack && tracking)
    {
        var point = {};
        point.x = event.clientX;
        point.y = event.clientY;
        ob.points.push(point);
    }
};
//mouse up
this.Up = function(event){
    if(conf.autoTrack && tracking)
    {
        ob.resolve(ob.points);
    }
    remove_event(document.body, "mousemove", ob.Move);
};


//some helping internal functions

var optCosDist = function(gestureV, inputV){
    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < gestureV.length; i += 2)
    {
        a = a + gestureV[i]*inputV[i] + gestureV[i+1]*inputV[i+1];
        b = b + gestureV[i]*inputV[i+1] - gestureV[i+1]*inputV[i];
    }
    var angle = Math.atan2(b,a);

    return Math.acos(a*Math.cos(angle) + b*Math.sin(angle));
};

//distance [PROTRACTOR]
var Distance = function(u, v){
    var x = (u.x - v.x);
    var y = (u.y - v.y);
    return Math.sqrt((x*x)+(y*y));
};

var pathLength = function(points, n){
    var distance = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        distance = distance + Distance(points[i-1], points[i]);
    }
    return distance;
};

var resample = function(points, n){
    var subLength = pathLength(points, n)/(conf.points-1);
    var distance = 0;
    var newpoints = [];
    var elem ={};
    elem.x = points[0].x;
    elem.y = points[0].y;
    newpoints.push(elem);

    var i = 1;
    while (i < points.length && newpoints.length < (conf.points-1))
    {
        var subdist = Distance(points[i-1], points[i]);
        if((distance + subdist) >= subLength)
        {
            var elem2 = {};
            elem2.x = points[i-1].x + ((subLength - distance)/subdist)*(points[i].x - points[i-1].x);
            elem2.y = points[i-1].y + ((subLength - distance)/subdist)*(points[i].y - points[i-1].y);
            //add point
            newpoints.push(elem2);
            points.splice(i,0,elem2);
            distance = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            distance = distance + subdist;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    var elem3 = {};
    //adding last point
    elem3.x = points[points.length-1].x;
    elem3.y = points[points.length-1].y;
    newpoints.push(elem3);

    return newpoints;
};

var centroid = function(points){
    var center = {};
    center.x = 0;
    center.y = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
    {
        center.x = center.x + points[i].x;
        center.y = center.y + points[i].y;
    }
    center.x = center.x/(points.length-1);
    center.y = center.y/(points.length-1);
    return center;
};

var translate = function(points,center){
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
    {
        points[i].x = points[i].x - center.x;
        points[i].y = points[i].y - center.y;
    }
    return points;
};

var vectorize = function(points, sensit){
    var vector = [];

    var center = centroid(points);
    var points = translate(points, center);

    var lenkis = Math.atan2(points[1].x, points[1].y);
    var delta = lenkis;
    if(sensit)
    {
        var base = (Math.PI/4)*Math.floor((lenkis+(Math.PI/8))*(4/Math.PI));
        delta = base-lenkis;
    }
    var summa = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
    {
        var newx = points[i].x*Math.cos(delta) - points[i].y*Math.sin(delta);
        var newy = points[i].x*Math.sin(delta) + points[i].y*Math.cos(delta);
        vector.push(newx);
        vector.push(newy);
        summa = summa + newx*newx + newy*newy;
    }

    var magnitude = Math.sqrt(summa);
    for(var i = 0; i < vector.length; i++)
    {
        vector[i] = vector[i]/magnitude;
    }
    return vector;
};

//get document dimensions
var doc_size = function(){
    var docsize = new Object();
    docsize.width = 0;
    docsize.height = 0;
    docsize.width = Math.max(
        Math.max(document.body.scrollWidth, document.documentElement.scrollWidth),
        Math.max(document.body.offsetWidth, document.documentElement.offsetWidth),
        Math.max(document.body.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
    docsize.height = Math.max(
        Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
    return docsize;
};

//add event
var add_event = function(element, type, listener){
    if(element.addEventListener)
    {
        element.addEventListener(type, listener, false);
    }
    else
    {
        element.attachEvent('on' +  type, listener);
    }
};

//remove event
var remove_event = function(element, type, listener){
    if(element.removeEventListener)
        element.removeEventListener(type, listener, false);
    else
        element.detachEvent('on' +  type, listener);
};

this.construct();
}
}
```